# Pendrive Won't Mount; Errror

Tags: mount, usb-drive, disk

My pen-drive won't mount, although it's working fine on my friend's system. I get the following error message:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/usb-hp_v210w_0419570000000162-0:0-part1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Answer (score 0):

`wrong fs type` errors caused while mounting an usb drive are mostly because of bad sectors in your current kernal.Updating your kernal will solve this issue.Run the following command to update your kernal,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

After that reboot your pc and then try to mount your usb.

Comment: no stii the same

Comment: i amm using Ubuntu 13.10 is that any problem

Comment: after that reboot your pc.

Comment: yes i did reeboot but that dosenot help

Comment: did your usb works on windows?

Comment: yes it still does

Comment: if you still facing this problem in windows,run disk check utility for finding bad-sectors.

Comment: no its working fine in windows

Comment: but it wont mount in ubuntu

Comment: run `fsck /dev/sdxx` where xx is your usb's last two label letters.